# In C, using GDimage to draw lines, what would be a good way to draw one line and produce other lines without repetition?

Tags: c, drawing

I'm doing a project for university where I have to draw multiple items using gdImage, I have no previous coding experience. If I was to draw a line and wanted multiple other lines also going round in a circular shape, what would be an efficient way of using that code from that one line to keep going around? Sorry if this is really obvious, thankyou for your help

```
gdImageLine ( gdImage, 50, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 100, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 150, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 200, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 250, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 300, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 350, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 400, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 450, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
 gdImageLine ( gdImage, 500, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning that you want to condense this down into less lines of code? If so, you can use a for loop as the only value that changes between each line of code is the second parameter of gdImageLine, which increments by 50 each line. This should do the trick.

```
int j = 50;  /* For increasing the second parameter of gdImageLine. */
int numberOfIterations = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
{
   gdImageLine( gdImage, j, 0, 250, 250, PocketGreen);
   j += 50;  /* Increase j by 50 each iteration. */
}
```